# Nextjs navigation super slow. Can I improve it?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nav

can you help me figure out why my nextjs navigation is super slow?
This is my code, so far.
Is it the placement of the Link element that makes it behave this way ?
At first when I tried it without the activeTabs it was faster. Are you aware of a proper way to structure the sidebar in order to have better loading times?

```
   
    
    const SidebarList = () => {
        const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0)
        return (
            <ul>
                <SidebarItem icon={"pi-home"} title={'Aρχική'} id={1} setActiveTab={setActiveTab} activeTab={activeTab} goTo={'/dashboard'} />
                {/* PRODUCT */}
                <SidebarHeader icon={"pi-shopping-cart"} title={'Προϊόντα'} id={2} setActiveTab={setActiveTab} activeTab={activeTab} goTo={'#'} dropdown />
                {activeTab == 2 ? (
                    <div >
                        <SidebarSubItem title={'Προϊον'} goTo={'/dashboard/product'} />
                        <SidebarSubItem title={'Μάρκες'} goTo={'/dashboard/product/brands'} />
                        <SidebarSubItem title={'Κατασκευαστές'} goTo={'/dashboard/product/manufacturers'} />
                        <SidebarSubItem title={'Κατηγορίες'} goTo={'/dashboard/product/mtrcategories'} />
                        <SidebarSubItem title={'Oμάδες'} goTo={'/dashboard/product/mtrgroup'} />
                        <SidebarSubItem title={'Υποομάδες'} goTo={'/dashboard/product/mtrsubgroup'} />
                    </div>
                ) : null}
                <SidebarHeader icon={"pi-shopping-cart"} title={'Τιμοκατάλογοι'} id={7} setActiveTab={setActiveTab} activeTab={activeTab} goTo={'#'} dropdown />
                {activeTab == 7 ? (
                    <div >
                        <SidebarSubItem title={'Upload Κατάλογοι'} goTo={'/dashboard/catalogs'} />
                        <SidebarSubItem title={'Αποθηκευμένοι Κατάλογοι'} goTo={'/dashboard/catalogs/saved'} />
                     
                    </div>
                ) : null}
                <SidebarItem icon={"pi-user"} title={'Πελάτες'} id={3} setActiveTab={setActiveTab} activeTab={activeTab} goTo={'#'} />
                <SidebarItem icon={"pi-user"} title={'Προμηθευτές'} id={4} setActiveTab={setActiveTab} activeTab={activeTab} goTo={'#'} />
                <SidebarItem icon={"pi-book"} title={'Impas'} id={5} setActiveTab={setActiveTab} activeTab={activeTab} goTo={'/dashboard/info/impas'} />
                <SidebarHeader icon={"pi-shopping-cart"} title={'Βοηθ. Πίνακες'} id={6} setActiveTab={setActiveTab} activeTab={activeTab} goTo={'#'} dropdown />
                {activeTab == 6 ? (
                    <div >
                        <SidebarSubItem title={'ΦΠΑ'} goTo={'/dashboard/info/vat'} />
                        <SidebarSubItem title={'Intrastat'} goTo={'/dashboard/info/intrastat'} />
                        <SidebarSubItem title={'Χώρες'} goTo={'/dashboard/info/countries'} />
                        <SidebarSubItem title={'Νόμισμα'} goTo={'/dashboard/info/currencies'} />
                    </div>
                ) : null}
            </ul>
        )
    }
    
    
    const SidebarHeader = ({ icon, id, setActiveTab, activeTab, title, dropdown }) => {
        const [activeIcon, setActiveIcon] = useState(false)
        const handleClick = () => {
            setActiveIcon(!activeIcon)
            setActiveTab((prev) => prev == id ? 0 : id)
        }
        return (
            <li onClick={handleClick} className={`sidebar-item ${activeTab == id ? "active" : null}`}>
                <div>
                    <i className={`pi ${icon}`} style={{ fontSize: '1rem' }}></i>
                    <span className='text-lg ml-3'>{title}</span>
                </div>
                {dropdown ? (<i className={` pi ${!activeIcon ? 'pi-angle-down' : 'pi-angle-up'}`} style={{ fontSize: '1rem' }}></i>) : null}
            </li>
        )
    }
    
    
    
    const SidebarItem = ({ icon, id, setActiveTab, activeTab, title, goTo }) => {
        const handleClick = () => {
            setActiveTab((prev) => prev == id ? 0 : id)
        }
        return (
    
                <li onClick={handleClick} className={`sidebar-item ${activeTab == id ? "active" : null}`}>
                    <Link href={goTo}>
                        <i className={`pi ${icon}`} style={{ fontSize: '1rem' }}></i>
                        <span className='text-lg ml-3'>{title}</span>
                    </Link>
                        
                </li>
    
        )
    }
    const SidebarSubItem = ({ title, goTo }) => {
        return (
    
          
                <li className={` sub-item`}>
                      <Link href={goTo}>
                        <span className='text-lg ml-3'>{title}</span>
                      </Link>
                </li>
          
    
        )
    }
```